# C# post upload file like curl.exe" -F

Tags: c#, curl, upload, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to duplicate the following curl functionality in C# but to no avail. I get a bad request returned with the C# code. The .NET code needs to replicate the curl file attachment/upload functionality. I would appreciate help.

"curl.exe" -F "attachment=@c:\data\img.jpg" "example.com"

```
    public static async void Post(string fileName)
    {
        string url = "example.com";
        var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
        string name = Path.GetFileName(fileName);

        var client = new HttpClient { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10) };

        var streamContent = new StreamContent(stream);
        streamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data");
        streamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name = "\"file\"";
        streamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "\"" + name + "\"";
        streamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent { streamContent };
        HttpResponseMessage message = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
        string s = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide the exact error message you are getting as well?

Comment: the bad format error is coming from the service itself that i am posting to. It appears to post the data, but my code apparently is not doing the same thing as the curl call.

Answer (score -1):

fixed my issue. "attachment" needed to be the file.